# Как добавить View элементы поверх других view элементов?

Tags: java, android

Всем привет, ребят. Разбираю для себя то что для меня не ясно. Например как на карту добавить `View` элемент? То есть карта и на ней была моя кнопка нажатия. И именно на ней чтоб на переднем фоне была кнопка на заднем карта, так же `EditText` ну и далее. И вообще как нужно ставить один `View` элемент поверх другого. Вы бы мне очень помогли, даже направив или коротко дав понять какой принцип...

Comment: http://startandroid.ru/ru/uroki/vse-uroki-spiskom/15-urok-6-vidy-layouts-kljuchevye-otlichija-i-svojstva.html

Comment: @AndrewGrow  Это я знаю  меня интересует вопрос однорго элемента поверх другого

Comment: хотите сказать через релятив или фрайм?)

Comment: да, эти два элемента очень помогут

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Карта отображается в специальном фрагменте `SupportMapFragment`. Соответственно вставьте этот фрагмент в ваш `layout` и в этот `layout` добавьте вам нужные `View` элементы

Пример:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <fragment xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:id="@+id/map"
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/search"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
        android:background="@android:color/white"
        android:padding="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
        android:text="@string/search"
        android:textColor="@android:color/darker_gray"
        tools:text="Search" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_margin="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
            android:id="@+id/myLocationBtn"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/margin_between_fab"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_my_location_black_24dp"
            app:backgroundTint="@android:color/white"
            app:elevation="0dp" />

        <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
            android:id="@+id/addMarkerBtn"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_add_black_24dp"
            app:backgroundTint="@android:color/white"
            app:elevation="0dp"
            app:fabSize="mini" />
    </LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: ААААААААААА   понел понел !!!!!Спасибо !!!